# Inheriting Styles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, styles, datatemplate

I have the following code in my MainWindow.xaml which follows Josh Smith's MVVM workspace model.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" 
      Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ContentControl
        Content="{Binding}" 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspaceTemplate}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Where initially my workspace template was

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                Margin="5,0,5,0">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I have created a `TabControl` style with close button which is contained in a seperate Resource Dictionary. The code for this is something like

```
<Style x:Key="StudioTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="StudioTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid Height="20" 
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                              Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              ContentSource="Header" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                    Width="15" 
                                    Height="15" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                            ... ect.
```

The question is how can I inherite this `StudioTabControl` style into my `<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">` definiation. Currently I have tried

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                Style="{StaticResource StudioTabControl}"
                ... ect.
```

but due to the fact that I specify `<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>...` in the `<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">` definiation the style does not work. **How can I get my `StudioTabItem` style to work with my existing `WorkspaceTemplate`?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource defined in Resources of any element can only be used inside that element so the style you defined in `TabControl.Style` will not be available outside it and hence won't be applied.

So in order to use that style take it out of the `Tabcontrol.Style` i.e. define it in parallel to your tabcontrol style in your resource dictionary.

Secondly if you have defined the Style with a key it will not be applied automatically. You will have to apply it explicitly using `{StaticResource=Key}.`

Once you define it outside the tabcontrol.Style, you can inherit it using BasedOn keyword in the ItemContainerStyle like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StudioTabItem}">
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how that's inheriting style, If you are looking for using "StudioTabControl" style inside "WorkspaceTemplate" just use it:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                Style="{StaticResource StudioTabControl}"
                Margin="5,0,5,0">
```

Its the TabControl style that you are looking for not TabItem style, because StudioTabItem's TargetType is TabItem not TabControl, so it wont get applied.

Alternatively if you are really looking for Style Inheritence the have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx).

Comment: I have shown that I have tried this in the question. The fact that I am using `<Style TargetType="TabItem" ` in the `<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">` stop the style being adopted properly/at all...

Comment: Have you noticed "StudioTabControl" instead of "StudioTabItem" in my code?

Comment: Yes I have. Sorry, this was a typo by me I will edit the question. This style the `TabControl` correctly but the `TabItem`s are not styled.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BasedOn` to inherit from a style:

```
 <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource StudioTabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style>
```

You need to define `StudioTabItem` so that it is accessible by your 'TabItem' style definition, so define this before you define `TabItem`:

```
 <Style x:Key="StudioTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
```

Comment: It does not let me do that. Instead when I do attempt it, it throws an XmlParseException '{"Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception."}'. I just want to get the `TabControl` within the `WorkspaceTemplate` to inherit my style - it seems so simple. Thanks for your time...

Comment: Thanks, but I have this in the definition already (shown in Line 3 of the third code snipped in the question). Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @Killercam: the style with the key `StudioTabItem` needs to be in the scope of the other style, right now it isn't. Define it *before* you reference it. Dont put it directly in `StudioTabControl`

Comment: Okay, but I am including the code for the `StudioTabControl/StudioTabItem` as a resource dictionary so it should pick this up right? I don't want to redefine the entire `Tabitem` style before I use it... Am I miss understanding you here?

Comment: Note, I can do `Style="{StaticResource StudioTabItem}"` and this works fine. How can I do as you suggest with out replicating all of the `<Style x:Key="StudioTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">...` code?